# Convert sub to function to use it as a formula

Tags: vba, excel

The below code is working fine with me. I need your help and support to make it a function so I can for example write in any cell 
`=adj()` or `=adj(A1)`  and the formula will apply,

```
Sub adj()

Dim i, j As Integer  
Sheet1.Select

With Sheet1    
    j = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)).Value    
    For i = 1 To j    
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)) & i & "))" & "&char(10)"       
    Next i       
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What would the formula do? It looks like currently it'll just take the cell's value (say `123` and add a number, parenthesis and a new line (`char(10)`)?

Comment: you are using `sheet1.select`, don't think this is suitable for use in function, unless u clarify what's the goal of the formula

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you wanted to pass change to a formula, and pass in the range, you would use something like:

```
Public Function Func(Byval MyRange as range) as variant
```

In this case, you're not specifying a return value so it will be ignored.

```
Public Function Func(Byval MyRange as range) as variant

Dim i, j As Integer  

With MyRange.parent    
    j = .Range(MyRange.Offset(0, -2), MyRange.Offset(0, -2)).Value    
    For i = 1 To j    
        MyRange.Formula = "=" & .Range(MyRange.Offset(0, -1), MyRange.Offset(0, -1)) & i & "))" & "&char(10)"       
    Next i       
End With

End Sub
```

It would be something like that..

Comment: Thank you, now I would like to make below a dynamic function

`Public Function adj(x As String, y As String) As String

Dim i, j As Integer

Dim t, z As String

Sheet1.Select

With Sheet1

j = x
z = Chr(10)
i = 1

If j = 3 Then
    
        t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))") & z & Evaluate(y & (i + 1) & "))") & z & Evaluate(y & (i + 2) & "))")

ElseIf j = 2 Then
   
        t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))") & z & Evaluate(y & (i + 1) & "))")

ElseIf j = 1 Then
    
        t = Evaluate(y & (i) & "))")
                  
End If


adj = t

End With


End Function`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to definitively understand what you're trying to do here. I think you're trying to concatenate x number of cells with a separator field.

So, I would do the following changes... obviously you can change accordingly.

1. Declare the Inputs as variants. If you don't and get a type mismatch the function wont call in debug. This also gives you the opportunity to deal with the Inputs.
2. Put in an error handler to prevent unwanted debug w.r.t. a failure.
3. You can't use Evaluate that way. I think you're trying to get an Evaluation of cells like A1 etc.
4. The function has to be called from a Cell on a sheet since it uses Application.Caller. You shouldn't really need this for the function to work, but I put in in there in case you are calling via F9 calculation.

You can also put in the line if you want the calculation to occur every time you recalculate. However this should be used with caution since you can get some unwanted calculation side effects with some spreadsheets when using this.

```
Application.Volatile 


Public Function Adj(ByVal x As Variant, ByVal y As Variant) As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim sSeparator As String, sCol As String
Dim i As Integer

'Get the column reference.
sCol = Split(Columns(y).Address(False, False), ":")(1)

'Activate the sheet.
Application.Caller.Parent.Select
    
sSeparator = Chr(10)
For i = 1 To x
    Adj = Adj & Evaluate(sCol & i) & sSeparator
Next
'Remove the last seperator...
Adj = Left(Adj, Len(Adj) - 1)

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    'Maybe do something with the error return value message here..
    'Although this is a string, Excel will implicitly convert to an error.
    Adj = "#VALUE!"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much , this is really helpfull